# Accessing RGBA components C-Style

Tags: casting, format, glsl, pixel

Is there any way to access the texture data in GLSL in a C-like fashion?
By that I mean, if I have fragment.rgba, can I, within the shader, cast fragment.rg to a short and use it that way?  I want to encode two pieces of scene information (two shorts) into a texture for use by another shader.

Edit: I'm declaring my texture this way:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, mWidth,mHeight, 0, GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mBits)
```

...and what I want to do in the shader would be done this way in C++:

```
short* aShortPtr=&fragment.rg;
*aShortPtr=10000;
aShortPtr=&fragment.ba
*aShortPtr=2500;
```

Now I realize that I can't actually do it this way in the shader, but the RGBA data is stored as  an integer anyway, so how can I write and read that integer instead of accessing everything as a vec4?

Comment: "*if I have fragment.rgba, can I, within the shader, cast fragment.rg to a short and use it that way?*" What is "fragment" in this example? Is that meant to be a vec4? And what does it have to do with a texture?

Comment: your pixelformat of the texture is `int` or `float`?

Comment: Spektre, this is how I declare the texture:
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, mWidth,mHeight, 0, GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mBits)

Comment: so they int you can use bitshifts and bitmasks ... along with texture fetch into `ivec4` ... see https://stackoverflow.com/q/71681945/2521214 also you should add @ before nick to enable site notifications ...